# Swift Playground Error: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: xcode, swift

Getting the above error with the following code in Playground Xcode 7.1.1:

```
import Cocoa

func countDivisors(number:Int) -> Int
{
    var c = 0
    for i in 1 ... number
    {
        if number % i == 0 { ++c }
    }
    return c
}

func isPrime(number:Int) -> Bool
{
    return countDivisors(number) == 2
}

isPrime(2);

for i in 0 ..< 100
{
    var f:Bool = isPrime(i)
    print("\(i): \(f)")
}
```

The error occurs on the line

```
var f:Bool = isPrime(i)
```

I already re-installed Xcode but error still appears. Does anyone know the reason behind this?

Comment: Side node: The test should start at 2 and stop when i >= the square root of the number. When you test the number 10,000, the test would finish after 1 % of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the line `var f:Bool = isPrime(i)` is called, initial value of i is 0, division by zero gives an unknown value. Better change your loop to `for i in 1 ..< 100`

Comment: The zero was the problem, but not because of division by zero—see RP's answer below for what was happening.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" is because the for loop's range operator cannot form a range with end value as 0. Your range operator's end value should be greater or equal to the start value.

From apple docs,

> The closed range operator (a...b) defines a range that runs from a to b, and includes the values a and b. The value of a must not be greater than b.

This will work

```
for i in 1...1 {
   //--  
}
```

but not this

```
for i in 1...0 {
  //--  
}
```